# How to save radio button value every on click event in angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I want to create angular application that can save radio button values into database in every on click event. In my previous application, I used php ajax to create it and work well. I use Codeigniter framework. Here's the code:

PHP and HTML code:

```
<form name="form" class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url();?>mahasiswa/konfirmasi">
    <?php
    $no=1;
    foreach($hasil->result() as $h){
        foreach($co->result() as $c){
            $idrecord = $c->id_record;
            $jwb = $c->jwb;
        }
    ?>
<input type="radio" name="jawab<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>" value="A" <?php if($h->jwb=='A'){echo 'checked';}?> onClick="simjwb(<?php echo $h->id_record;?>,<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>,<?php echo $no;?>)"/>a.&nbsp;</div><?php echo $h->a;?>
<input type="radio" name="jawab<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>" value="B" <?php if($h->jwb=='B'){echo 'checked';}?> onClick="simjwb(<?php echo $h->id_record;?>,<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>,<?php echo $no;?>)"/>b.&nbsp;</div><?php echo $h->b;?>
<input type="radio" name="jawab<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>" value="C" <?php if($h->jwb=='C'){echo 'checked';}?> onClick="simjwb(<?php echo $h->id_record;?>,<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>,<?php echo $no;?>)"/>c.&nbsp;</div><?php echo $h->c;?>
<?php   
$no++;
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id_sesi" id="idse" value="<?php echo $h->id_sesi;?>">
<?php
}
?>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function simjwb(co,so,no){
//alert("gagal koneksi");
var se = document.getElementById("idse").value;
var jw = $("input:radio[name=jawab"+so+"]:checked").val();
//$.post('<?php echo site_url("mahasiswa/uprec/");?>',{ id_record: co, id_soal: so, id_sesi: se, jwb: jw });
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: { id_record: co, id_soal: so, id_sesi: se, jwb: jw },
        url: "<?php echo site_url("mahasiswa/uprec/");?>"
    });
    $('#no'+no).attr('class','panel panel-success');
    $('#s'+no).attr('class','sdh');
}
```

How to implement this in angularjs? What should I use `ng-click` or `ng-model` or something else? And how to parse expression in angularjs function following in my ajax function `onClick="simjwb(<?php echo $h->id_record;?>,<?php echo $h->id_soal;?>,<?php echo $no;?>)"` so I can get `id_record, id_soal, $no` to post in my `simjwb(expressions)` function?

Sorry for long code and my bad English. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use both ng-click and ng-model.

```
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red" ng-click="saveValue()">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="green" ng-click="saveValue()">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue" ng-click="saveValue()">
    Blue
  </label>
```

in controller you can define the saveValue function, something like below

```
$scope.saveValue=function(){
    $http.post("/test/save",$scope.color);
}
```

Best practice is to create a service which will take care of making http calls and inject that service in your controller

Comment: by the way, how to get my id_record, id_soal, $no from view (form) to pass the into controller so they can be post (insert) into database?

Comment: you can assign everything to a scope object like $scope.formData.idRecord etc along with radio button value and then post the whole object to your rest endpoint

Comment: how to assign my 3 expressions in one radio button? I'm sorry I'm still new in angularjs...

Comment: you cant assign three expressions in one radio button. You will have to create the objects in scope and based on which radio button is clicked you can pass the relevant object to server

Comment: excuse me, can you give me example how to create the objects in scope?